# How to define a function that returns an object of the same class?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-html

I am doing this example [tutorial](https://caveli.medium.com/programaci%C3%B3n-as%C3%ADncrona-con-dart-flutter-en-el-foco-a613fb0e8a27) on async functions and reviewing this section

```dart
import 'dart:io';

class ProceessedData {
  ProceessedData(this.data);

  final String data;

  Future<String> empty() {
    return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4),
        () => HttpException('http://www.google.com.').toString());
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  Future<String> _loadFromDisk() {
    return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4), () => 'Lectura de disco');
  }

  Future<String> _fetchNetworkData(String codigo) {
    return Future.delayed(
        const Duration(seconds: 4), () => 'lectura de red codigo $codigo');
  }

  Future<ProceessedData> createData() async {
    try {
      final id = await _loadFromDisk();
      final data = await _fetchNetworkData('4');
      return ProceessedData(data);
    } on HttpException catch (err) {
      print('Network error: $err');
      return ProceessedData.empty();
    } finally {
      print('All done!');
    }
  }
}
```

I see that in the exception `ProceessedData.empty()` which I must define in my main class since it does not exist but I thought it should be defined in the following way

```dart
  Future<String> empty() {
    return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4),
        () => HttpException('http://www.google.com.').toString());
  }
```

but when validating, this error is still indicated

[image]

**If it is clear to me, I am returning a future value of type string and that the function that I have created `createData()` indicates that it will return a `ProcessedData` but I do not know how I should define the `empty()` function so that it returns an instance of its same class (I feel like if you were looking to loop)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `ProcessedData.empty()` is to create a new instance of `ProcessedData` (not `String`) which has no data. The fact that it is called directly on the `ProcessedData` class, means that `empty()` is either a static method, a factory constructor, or a named constructor (any of those will do).

It also doesn't need to return a `Future` - There is no need to wait for anything to get an instance of empty data. The fact that `createData` is an async method means that *any* value returned from the method will already be wrapped in a `Future`, so you can just return a `ProcessedData`.

With all that in mind, you can define `empty` like this:

```dart
class ProcessedData {
  // ...

  factory ProcessedData.empty() => ProcessedData("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's because you are returning a `String` when calling `ProcessedData.empty()`.

You can change the method `empty` to be a named constructor then it will work properly.

Your `ProcessedData` class:

```
class ProcessedData {
    ProcessedData(this.data);

    final String data;

    Future<String> empty() {
        return Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4),
            () => HttpException('http://www.google.com.').toString());
    }
}
```

Change it to:

```
class ProcessedData {
    ProcessedData(this.data);

    final String data;

    ProcessedData.empty() :
        data = HttpException('http://www.google.com.').toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're adding Future.delayed in your Data class but the error is that you're trying to return a String to a ProceessedData

I would do sonething like this:

```
class ProceessedData {
  ProceessedData(this.data);

  final String data;

  factory ProceessedData.empty() {
    return ProcessedData('');
  }
}
```